# Does <fb:visible-to-connection> work anymore?

Tags: php, facebook, fbml

I have this code in my page tab for my page, and it always says hello, on my page and my friends page and neither have us have liked it. i'm an admin and he is not.

```
<fb:fbml version="1.1">
<fb:visible-to-connection>hello</fb:visible-to-connection>
</fb:fbml>
```

Is there anything i forgot to add, or does this just not work anymore since they are deprecating FBML?

Answer (score 0):

You really should be migrating all your code to the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/). It's really the only dependable and scalable Facebook interface available.

Comment: I don't want to ask for permission if they are a fan or not, which is why i liked this tag and used it a lot awhile ago.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is deprecating FBML (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/), which will not be supported from Jan 1, 2012 and after Jun 1, 2012, no apps using FBML will work. You should start using the one of the [SDKs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/) provided by Facebook, [Open Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) or [Social Plugins](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/).

Comment: Obviously, but you can't use this tag without asking for permission, and i figured it out no thanks to anyone here.